# Getting country name from IP php with iptolatlng.com

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, ip-geolocation

What i am trying to do is get the country name from the IP address.
I have created a class named General and in that class I have a function called GetIPCountry($ip) which returns the jason decoded array from the iptolatlng.com

```
public function GetIPCountry($ip){
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.iptolatlng.com?`ip=".urlencode($ip)));`
    return $details->countryFullName;
}
```

when i send my ip like this in my localhost:

```
$country = $general->GetIPCountry('***.***.***.**');
```

it works just fine!

But when I send upload the same file and run it in my server, there is no output.

I thought since I am on the server I should try the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` too but this doesn't show any result too.
I suspect this could be a server error too, I am hosted at iPage
Please help me,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First - you have error in your syntax (not needed ` both in the URL and on the end of the line).

Correct your mistake and post what phpfiddle posts: ([link]http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b3f-gvi[/link].
Then, if it's corrected on your remote server, and you still have no output, an error probably occurs and you have set PHP flag 'display_errors' set to 0.

In that case try pasting this before your code:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Kleskowy Thank you for pointing out, but that was just a mistake when I was copying the syntax here. I have made the a phpfidle this is the link, basically this is what i do! http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mih-iqn

Comment: @Kleskowy actually I coppied your code into my server and still it doesn't work. Eventhought both my code and your code work fine at fiddle it should work in the remote server too right?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick question: what does $ip contain when you host it on the remote server? In essence, if you were to print out $ip, does it contain your IP address? This will help you to figure out if it is an issue with getting the IP address of the connected computer or otherwise.

Comment: $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; its like that. when I echo this I get my IP address without any trouble

Comment: So then it should call the iptolatng page for that IP, and store it in the details. And $details contains nothing after that call when run on the remote server?

Comment: Yes!! Thats the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending 127.0.0.1 as the IP?  If you are asking the service the location of IP 127.0.0.1, it won't be able to tell you what your location is.  I had this problem when running your code from my localhost.

Comment: I am not trying to do that, I have my script uploaded to a remote server, thats where I am testing that. check my fiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mih-iqn

Comment: I have Uploaded and tested this on a different server, it works fine. Could this be a server problem? I now suspect highly and eventhough iPages customer support is constantly telling me that this is a Server problem.

Comment: try testing this out by removing the ?ip= parameter on the end of your fiddle.  try: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v93-8er

guess is that your server has an issue with REMOTE_ADDR for some reason

Comment: can you print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and share the contents of that printout?

Answer (score 0):

Here there are two plugins that work

http://taylorlopes.com/?p=636

and this one: http://www.geoplugin.com/

i preferred the second one

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question but might help - why not use the geoip PECL extension? 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php

With this you won't have to go out to an external web server for the result, and won't be dependent on a 3rd party service downtime.